# Bootstrap collapse content is not hiding back

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

The bootstrap collapsed content doesn't hide back when I click the toggler again.

Head ->

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
</head>
```

body ->

```
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            ></script>
</body>
```

Collapse content ->

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
        <h3 class="me-3"> <%= teamName %> </h3>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#<%= idName %>" data-bs-parent="#accordion" aria-controls="<%= idName %>" aria-expanded="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v5.793L5.354 8.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V4.5z"/>
        </svg></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="<%= idName %>">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row mt-n1-9">
                <%- include('./memberCard', {name: "abc", position: "a", imgSrc : "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", facebook: "#", insta: "#", linkedIn: "#"}) %>
                <%- include('./memberCard', {name: "def", position: "b", imgSrc : "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", facebook: "#", insta: "#", linkedIn: "#"}) %>
                <%- include('./memberCard', {name: "ghi", position: "c", imgSrc : "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", facebook: "#", insta: "#", linkedIn: "#"}) %>
                <%- include('./memberCard', {name: "klm", position: "d", imgSrc : "https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png", facebook: "#", insta: "#", linkedIn: "#"}) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried a lot of solutions available, but unfortunately none of them worked for me. Please help me solve this issue

PS: The head and body tag are inside a boilerplate and I'm including the collapsed content code from another file.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice and bootstrap twice? You have `jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js` which you don't need. You have `popper.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` - both are included in `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`. Are you getting any errors in your dev console?

Comment: @disinfor No, the console is not showing any error. I looked up for some solutions on here and they suggested to add this and this script or links and I got confused which one to keep.